# How is the process memory allocated on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory

When I build this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("a = %p\n", &a);
    printf("argv = %p\n", argv);
}
```

I can see

```
a = 0x7f123ec0101c
argv = 0x7ffff0a27618
```

Knowing the arguments are located on the top of the stack, the variables juste after the code segment, I can conclude that the allocated memory for this program is `&argv - &a` which is `(argv - a) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 950 GiB` which seems not realistic.

I also know that the stack size is 8 KiB:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

I guess the operating system would do a memory mapping between virtual addresses and real memory adresses using the MMU, but in this case why is the base memory something like `0x7f123ec0101c` and not `0x0000000000` and how is the top memory address chosen?

Comment: The memory is *virtual*. Even though you see ~1TB allocated it doesn't mean that *all* of this space is available all-together.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is *virtual* :)

Comment: So what is the problem? It can allocate page here and there, and the space does not have to be contiguous.

Comment: The question is how is this virtual memory adresses chosen and by who.

Comment: `cat /proc/self/maps` might give you a hint. You will probably notice slight differences in the addresses each time you perform this command, this is due to ASLR. But the vincity is usually always the same

Comment: @Ctx, good hint, thanks

Comment: The value from `ulimit -s` has units of kilobytes, so the stack size is limited to 8 MiB.

Comment: Usually it is recommended to include few (or many) guard pages between the stack and other memory to prevent/easily detect stack overflows. Do you have ASLR enabled?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It seems you discovered that I am running on WSL :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you say "MiB", you also have to say "kibibytes", as ugly as it may read and sound ;)

Comment: @Ctx — I plead guilty to inconsistency; mitigating circumstances include severe under-caffeination. I should have used KiB to avoid writing out kibibytes (and the auto-correcting spelling-mangler had a field day with kibibytes!).

Comment: @Ctx I am also wondering if it is better to use `octet` instead of `byte`. It iseems the term `byte` is ambiguous :(

Comment: @nowox no, it is not ambiguous, it is just something else than an octet (or lets say, an octet is a _special case_ of a byte). A byte is the smallest unit, which has an own memory address. An octet is a byte consisting of 8 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil my mistake!

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1. Allocation of arguments is done by `exec`, not a startup code, and 2. `a` is global, and is likely in `bss`, not on stack.